# unable to format sony usb 8gb drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive, troubleshooting

when i inserted the drive the files are appearing like this [image]

but when i rightclicked on that path it is showing create folder and create file options.but when i tried to create it it is giving an error.

```
Error creating directory: Read-only file system
```

fdisk output

```
#sudo fdisk -l
Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 7998 MB, 7998537728 bytes
247 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1020 cylinders, total 15622144 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x500a0dff

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?  1948285285  3650263507   850989111+  6e  Unknown
/dev/sdb2   ?           0           0           0   74  Unknown
/dev/sdb3               0           0           0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb4        28049408    28049848         220+   0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

and i tried

```
sudo mkfs.fat -I /dev/sdb*
```

it worked but after when i inserted the drive it is not mounting so i tried

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb* /mnt
```

when i tried to list out the files by using

```
ls
```

my system suddenly rebooted after rebooting when i tried i got this error this time totally its not mounted.

```
 Error mounting /dev/sdb at /media/ashokkrishna/MAHIYOGI: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb" "/media/ashokkrishna/MAHIYOGI"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
```

when i opened gparted tried to create the partition table it is the error i got.
[image]

and when i removed the drive and inserted again it given this output but it didn't asked to create partition table.

[image]

but when i tried to check the problem and correct it my system got hanged and shutdowned.

Comment: Have you tried using Disks or Gparted ?? No download needed they are both incorporated in Ubuntu.

Comment: But did they help?? (I can't help you in the commands because I'm new on that and I don't want to give you wrong information)

Comment: i tried to create partition table in the pendrive. updated the erro in my question.

Comment: Don't you already have a partition table ??

Comment: nope. i haven't

Comment: now it behaved again differently .

Comment: If it possible try to format in windows OS.

Comment: no i tried that earlier.

Comment: pls anyone solve  the problem. i am in need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the new partition table using `parted` from the command line:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
```

Then you can just try to create the partition and the filesystem using Gparted.

If it doesn't work, create the partition table and the partition using `parted` from the command line:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos mkpart primary 2048s 100%
```

Then create the filesystem using `mkfs.fat`:

```
mkfs.fat /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: i removed the drive and when i inserted it it didnt asked to create partition tables. this time.